# React Native, problem importing new SVG into project

Tags: react-native

I have a problem that after adding a new SVG I get an error, but before that I have already added other SVGs and everything worked.

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
transform[stdout]: Error: Missed `structure` field in `UnicodeRange` node type definition
transform[stdout]:     at getTypesFromConfig (C:\Users\botwi\Desktop\app\my-app\node_modules\csso\node_modules\css-tree\cjs\walker\create.cjs:71:23)
transform[stdout]:     at Object.createWalker (C:\Users\botwi\Desktop\app\my-app\node_modules\csso\node_modules\css-tree\cjs\walker\create.cjs:153:19)
transform[stdout]:     at createSyntax (C:\Users\botwi\Desktop\app\my-app\node_modules\csso\node_modules\css-tree\cjs\syntax\create.cjs:13:27)
transform[stdout]:     at createSyntax$1 (C:\Users\botwi\Desktop\app\my-app\node_modules\csso\node_modules\css-tree\cjs\syntax\create.cjs:54:34)
transform[stdout]:     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\botwi\Desktop\app\my-app\node_modules\csso\node_modules\css-tree\cjs\syntax\index.cjs:8:16)
transform[stdout]:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
transform[stdout]:     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
transform[stdout]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
transform[stdout]:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
transform[stdout]:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
Android Bundling failed 2658ms
error: assets\search.svg: Module "@svgr/plugin-svgo" missing. Maybe `npm install @svgr/plugin-svgo` could help!
```

*"npm install @svgr/plugin-svgo" didn't work

The problem is not in the SVG, before I had the same problem, but I solved it simply by creating a new project and transferring everything there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I use the React Native SVG and works fine.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue but with css-what.
css-what was resolved to a version that is older than css-select in @svgr/plugin-svgo required. Added below packages to resolutions fixed the problem.

```
  "resolutions": {
    ...
    "@svgr/plugin-svgo": "8.1.0",
    "svgo": "3.0.2",
    "css-tree": "2.2.1",
    "css-select": "5.1.0",
    "css-what": "6.1.0",
  }
```